# Get localized language name from locale code

Tags: python, locale

How can I get localized language name by specified locale code in python?

For example:

```
>> get_language_name('ja')
>> ('Japanese', u'日本語')
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/) package can help:

```
>>> from babel import Locale
>>> locale = Locale('ja', 'JP')
>>> print locale.display_name
日本語 (日本)
```

There is also [PyICU](http://pyicu.osafoundation.org/), a Python wrapper for the [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) library.